# Of vs For in “The Institute of/for Wildlife Research”

Tags: prepositions

Is there a difference between saying:

- The Institute **for** Wildlife Research

and

- The Institute **of** Wildlife Research

Comment: Saying "for" could be construed that it is an institute in favor of wild life research, like possibly an institution whose involvement in wildlife research is indirect by merely supporting and/or sponsoring wildlife research done externally by other people and organizations. Saying "of" will only be construed as the institute being directly engaged in wildlife research, meaning doing research itself. My personal preference, however, would be *Wildlife Research Institute* for its succinctness.

Comment: thank you ! more clear now